# Regex syntax error in IDLE, but not in my program for Python?

Tags: regex, syntax, python-idle

I've benefited from the knowledge of the stackoverflow community for years. Finally found an issue I couldn't figure out how to look up ...

I am using the Python IDLE Shell 3.9.5 on Windows 10. Here is what I enter.

```
import re
txt="That will be 59 dollars"
x = re.findall("\d", txt)
x
['5', '9']
```

That is just what one would expect.

Now try this:

```
if True : x = re.findall("\d", txt)
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence \d
```

The line of code does not execute due to the syntax error. The first double quote in the line is highlighted by the Shell.

In my working code, the 'if True :' expression is, of course, a more useful conditional expression.  I've simplified it to illustrate the issue.

There is no syntax error if this code is a Python script which is run from the command line or if the script is opened in the IDLE Shell and run.

BTW for those who are curious, the 'txt' line comes from an example on https://www.w3schools.com/
The code works fine in their online interpreter as well.

What exactly is the syntax error occurring in the compound statement which does not occur in the simple statement?   ... and why?   Thx for your help.

Comment: Your code works in Python 3.9.5. You need to check the code you did not share. However, make sure you use a raw string literal, `r"\d"`, not `"\d"`.

Answer (score 1):

Like all question askers providing code, you should read how to create a [minimal but complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In particular, it says to strip away everything that is not essential to the problem, and which is therefore distracting noise.  In this case, the re module is irrelevant. Here is the minimal code, run in interactive 3.9.7:

```
>>> '\d'
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
'\\d'
>>> if True: '\d'
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
...
'\\d'
```

The warning means that in the future, the invalid escape sequence '\d' will become a syntax error (in 3.11 or later).  The warnings started in 3.9 and continue in 3.10.

Here is the same example in 3.9.7 IDLE.

```
>>> '\d'
'\\d'
>>> if True: '\d'
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence '\d'
```

Deprecation warnings are currently not printed.  But why the premature SyntaxError?  IDLE uses code.InteractiveInterpreter and runs shell input with its .runsource method.  That in turn used codeop, which uses builtin compile() with some extra tricks.  So I tried:

```
>>> import code
>>> ii = code.InteractiveInterpreter()
>>> ii.runsource("'\d'")
'\\d'
False
>>> ii.runsource("if 1:'\d'")
  File "<input>", line 1
    if 1:'\d'
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence '\d'
False
>>>
```

'False' is the return value of runsource, which means that the statement was complete and no more lines of input are needed.  IDLE does not print the return value when it calls runsource internally.

The error indicates that neither you nor IDLE did anything wrong.  There is an error somewhere in codeop or perhaps compile().  I will open an issue on the tracker.  Thanks for reporting this anomaly.

EDIT: Wiktor [see comments] is correct that one immediate solution is to use the 'r' prefix.  Either that or doubled '\' will eventually be required.

EDIT 2: Rewrite everything after `import code` above after you (D Davis) pointed out my code mistake.

Comment: Terry, try this:

`II.runsource('if 1: "\d"')`

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  The first call also needed double quotation.  I rewrote the end of my answer in response.